# Failed to start apache2.service: Unit apache2.service not found

Tags: server, apache2, php, xampp

I just installed xampp in my ubuntu 16.04 and now my server is not running. If I run this command to start apache `sudo systemctl start apache2` I get this error `Failed to start apache2.service: Unit apache2.service not found.` Another problem is when I run `php -v` I get this message

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqlnd.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqlnd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/xml.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/xml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/dom.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/dom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mbstring.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mbstring.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mcrypt.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/simplexml.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/simplexml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/wddx.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/wddx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/xmlreader.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/xmlreader.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/xmlwriter.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/xmlwriter.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/xsl.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/xsl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

I could not find any solution so far. It would be nice if someone could help me.

Comment: So, apache2 was running well before installing xampp?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't check. I just started with php and thought first installing xampp.

Comment: So you never actually installed `apache2`?

Comment: xampp include everything, isnt't it?

Comment: what command did you run to install xampp?

Comment: I downloaded the installer and then sudo ./-----.run